# Display list of Accounts user is on AccountTeam for in VF page

Tags: apex

Something missing here, basic - I am getting nothing in my VF page even though I have one Account setup to meet the conditions:

```
public class UsersNeglectedAccounts {

    public UsersNeglectedAccounts(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }

    List <AccountTeamMember> ATMS = [select  AccountID from AccountTeamMember where UserID =:userinfo.getuserId()];

      Set<Id> accountIds = (new Map<Id,AccountTeamMember>(ATMS )).keySet();


    public List<Account> getAccounts() {
      return [select name, lastActivityDate  from Account where Neglected__c = true and ID IN: accountIDs ];
    }

}
```

Are the Accountids not getting into the set?
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to lazy load your queries. You are also mapping by the `Id` of the `AccountTeamMember` where you should use `AccountId`.

```
Set<Id> accountIds
{
    get
    {
        if (accountIds == null)
        {
            accountIds = new Set<Id>();
            for (AccountTeamMember teamMember : [
                SELECT AccountId FROM AccountTeamMember
                WHERE UserId = :UserInfo.getUserId()])
            {
                accountIds.add(teamMember.AccountId);
            }
        }
        return accountIds
    }
    private set;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**accountIds** is actually holding the IDs of AccountTeamMember objects rather than accounts. In this case, you won't be able to use that fancy Map shorthand; you'll have to loop through **ATMS** and add each AccountId to the set manually.